# This Postgresql ROLLUP grouping is not working for a Window expression

Tags: postgresql, group-by, rollup

The following SQL works well; it gives me the result I want for the counts and percentage: (please use EXTRACT (YEAR|MONTH|DAY ...) where required):

```
SELECT YEAR(evt_date) AS yr, MONTH(evt_date) AS mth, DAY(evt_date) AS dy, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       ROUND(COUNT(*)*100 / (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(evt_date), MONTH(evt_date))), 2) AS prct
   FROM my_data
   WHERE evt_date >= '2023-11-01'
   GROUP BY yr, mth, dy
   ORDER BY 1,2,3
   ;
```

But if I introduce the ROLLUP in, I get the cnt totals fine but not the totals for percentages where the window expression is used. **This must be a bug** but I have no way to report it to be fixed:

```
SELECT YEAR(evt_date) AS yr, MONTH(evt_date) AS mth, DAY(evt_date) AS dy, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       ROUND(COUNT(*)*100 / (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(evt_date), MONTH(evt_date))), 2) AS prct
   FROM my_data
   WHERE evt_date >= '2023-11-01'
   GROUP BY yr, ROLLUP (mth, dy)    -- ROLLUP does not give the the result I expect to see for the percentage column
   ORDER BY 1,2,3
   ;
```

Does anybody knows why? I am using Postgresql v12.

I have this alternative solution with tricks, but it is weird the one above doesn't work:

```
WITH my_data(evt_date, foo) AS
      (SELECT '2023-11-01'::DATE, 'X' UNION
       SELECT '2023-11-01', 'Y' UNION
       SELECT '2023-11-02', 'X' UNION
       SELECT '2023-11-02', 'Y' UNION
       SELECT '2024-01-01', 'X' UNION
       SELECT '2024-01-01', 'Y' UNION
       SELECT '2024-01-01', 'Z' UNION
       SELECT '2024-01-02', 'X' UNION
       SELECT '2024-01-02', 'Y' UNION
       SELECT '2024-01-03', 'X' UNION
       SELECT '2024-01-03', 'Y' UNION
       SELECT '2024-01-03', 'Z' UNION
       SELECT '2024-01-03', 'W' 
      ),
    totals AS
      (SELECT YEAR(evt_date) AS yr, MONTH(evt_date) AS mth, DAY(evt_date) AS dy, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
               ROUND(COUNT(*)*100 / (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(evt_date), MONTH(evt_date))), 2) AS prct
           FROM my_data
           WHERE evt_date >= '2023-11-01'
           GROUP BY yr, mth, dy 
           ORDER BY 1,2,3 
      )
   SELECT yr, mth, dy, SUM(cnt) AS cnt, SUM(prct) AS prct --<-- Fake SUM() to be able to use ROLLUP
     FROM totals
     GROUP BY yr, ROLLUP (mth, dy)  --- Only way? for ROLLUP to handle the percentage column well
      ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: Would you mind attaching a `create` statement for the tables/columns involved, an `insert` of sample/mock records, the results you're getting right now and what you'd expect to get instead? That would make it reproducible and easier to discuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example.
First, `prct` calculation can be before `ROLLUP`.

And, You calculate sum()over(partition by `yr,mth`), therefore ROLLUP can be (`dy`).

```
select yr,mth,dy,sum(prct) pct
from (
SELECT extract(year from evt_date) AS yr
   , extract(MONTH from evt_date) AS mth
   , extract(DAY from evt_date) AS dy
   , COUNT(*) AS cnt
   , ROUND(COUNT(*)*100 / 
         (SUM(COUNT(*)) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY extract(year from evt_date), extract(MONTH from evt_date)))
      , 2) AS prct
FROM my_data
WHERE evt_date >= '2023-11-01'
GROUP BY evt_date
)x
group by yr,mth,rollup(dy)
ORDER BY 1,2,3
;
```

Output

| yr | mth | dy | pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 11 | 1 | 50.00 |
| 2023 | 11 | 2 | 50.00 |
| 2023 | 11 | null | 100.00 |
| 2024 | 1 | 1 | 33.33 |
| 2024 | 1 | 2 | 22.22 |
| 2024 | 1 | 3 | 44.44 |
| 2024 | 1 | null | 99.99 |

With partition by `yr` and rollup(`mth,dy`)

```
select yr,mth,dy,sum(prct) pct
from (
SELECT extract(year from evt_date) AS yr
   , extract(MONTH from evt_date) AS mth
   , extract(DAY from evt_date) AS dy
   , COUNT(*) AS cnt
   , ROUND(COUNT(*)*100 / 
         (SUM(COUNT(*)) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY extract(year from evt_date)))
      , 2) AS prct
FROM my_data
WHERE evt_date >= '2023-11-01'
GROUP BY evt_date
)x
group by yr,rollup(mth,dy)
ORDER BY 1,2,3
;
```

output

| yr | mth | dy | pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 11 | 1 | 50.00 |
| 2023 | 11 | 2 | 50.00 |
| 2023 | 11 | null | 100.00 |
| 2023 | null | null | 100.00 |
| 2024 | 1 | 1 | 33.33 |
| 2024 | 1 | 2 | 22.22 |
| 2024 | 1 | 3 | 44.44 |
| 2024 | 1 | null | 99.99 |
| 2024 | null | null | 99.99 |

I do not know what the point is here.

Comment: My point is that there must be a bug. There should not be way-arounds and tricks to make this work. Thanks for your answer and for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This query calculates the count and percentage (prct) for each day (dy) within each month (mth) and year (yr). Then, it applies the ROLLUP function to summarize the data for each month and year combination. Finally, it orders the results by year, month, and day.

**Example:**

```
WITH monthly_data AS (
    SELECT 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM evt_date) AS yr,
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM evt_date) AS mth,
        EXTRACT(DAY FROM evt_date) AS dy,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        ROUND(
            COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM evt_date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM evt_date)),
            2
        ) AS prct
    FROM my_data
    WHERE evt_date >= '2023-11-01'
    GROUP BY yr, mth, dy
)
SELECT 
    yr,
    mth,
    dy,
    SUM(cnt) AS cnt,
    SUM(prct) AS prct
FROM monthly_data
GROUP BY yr, mth, dy WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY yr, mth, dy;
```

**Output:**

| yr | mth | dy | pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 11 | 1 | 50.0 |
| 2023 | 11 | 2 | 50.0 |
| 2023 | 11 | 3 | 100.0 |
| 2024 | 1 | 1 | 33.3 |
| 2024 | 1 | 2 | 33.3 |
| 2024 | 1 | 3 | 33.3 |
| 2024 | 1 | null | 100.0 |
| 2024 | null | null | 100.0 |